# Several buttons in one line

Tags: php, yii2

How could I post two buttons in one horizontal line?

```
<div style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'one_week_ago', 'method' => 'GET',]) ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="one_week_ago">

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Прошлая неделя', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'last1']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    <?php $form1 = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'two_week_ago', 'method' => 'GET']); ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="two_week_ago" >

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Позапрошлая неделя', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'last2']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end();?>


</div>
```

There are in different ActiveForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
float:left;
```

as css commands for both buttons.
For example:

```
<div class="form-group" style="float:left;">
```

Make sure to close the floating by adding

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

before

```
<?php ActiveForm::end();?>
```